# Scrollable fixed Div with height 100%

Tags: css

I have a div that contains text. This div is fixed and should fill the remaining height that is available when it needs more space. If the content is longer then `height: 100%` it should scroll.

The only thing I could think of was this approach:

```
.container {
  width: 300px
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto; 
  position: fixed;
}
```

but it did not work out. Is there a way without setting a fixed `px` size?

Comment: please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you.

Comment: in what way it *did not work*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to cover 100% viewport height, use `100vh`.

```css
.container {background: red; height: 100vh;}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this solution :)

```css
body {
  background-color:red;
}
.container {
  position:fixed;
  top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
  overflow-y:auto;
  background-color:grey;
}
.spacer {
  width:10px;
  height:200vh;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```